# Given a list of coefficients, create a polynomial

Tags: sage, polynomials, coefficients

I want to create a polynomial with given coefficients. This seems very simple but what I have found till now did not appear to be the thing I desired.
For example in such an environment;

```
n = 11
K = GF(4,'a')
R = PolynomialRing(GF(4,'a'),"x")
x = R.gen()
a = K.gen()
v = [1,a,0,0,1,1,1,a,a,0,1]
```

Given a list/vector v of length n (I will set this n and v at the begining), I want to get the polynomial `v(x)` as `v[i]*x^i`. 
(Actually after that I am going to build the quotient ring `GF(4,'a')[x] /< x^n-v(x) >` after getting this `v(x)` from above) then I will say;

```
S = R.quotient(x^n-v(x), 'y')
y = S.gen()
```

But I couldn't write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question in many places so it is better to leave it here as an answer although the answer I have is so simple:

I just wrote `R(v)` and it gave me the polynomial:

```
sage
n = 11
K = GF(4,'a')
R = PolynomialRing(GF(4,'a'),"x")
x = R.gen()
a = K.gen()

v = [1,a,0,0,1,1,1,a,a,0,1]
R(v)

x^10 + a*x^8 + a*x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + a*x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically (that is, ignoring the specifics of your polynomial ring) you have a list/vector v of length n and you require a polynomial which is the sum of all v[i]*x^i. Note that this sum equals the matrix product V.X where V is a one row matrix (essentially equal to the vector v) and X is a column matrix consisting of powers of x. In **Maxima** you could write

v: [1,a,0,0,1,1,1,a,a,0,1]$
n: length(v)$
V: matrix(v)$
X: genmatrix(lambda([i,j], x^(i-1)), n, 1)$
V.X;

The output is

x^10+a*x^8+a*x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+a*x+1